# How to generate pdf files in Magento

Tags: magento, zend-framework

I have to generate a prduct list within a pdf file in Magento.

How can I use Zend_Pdf to do that ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I've found Zend_Pdf to be a little challenging to use. The way I was using it was to create a "template" pdf in some other program (i used open office calc). Saving that somewhere in the magento installation and calling

```
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load('filename.pdf');
```

The next is to modify the pages. Mine only had one page, so I used

```
$page = $pdf->pages[0];
```

This grabs the first (and only page). To use text you have to set the font. Then draw text.

```
$page->setFont(Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA), 8);
$page->drawText($currentDate, 490, 702);
```

You said you would like to create a list of products, so you could do something like. It's very hackish, since you have to draw text with coordinates.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$amountToSubtract = 0;
$beginningVerticalPosition = 480;
foreach ($products as $product)
{
    $vert = $beginningVerticalPosition - $amountToSubtract;
    $page->drawText($product['sku'], 40, $vert);
    $page->drawText($product['name'], 150, $vert);
    $amountToSubtract = $amountToSubtract + 13;
}
```

Then you have to render it as application/pdf instead of html. I'm not sure how you're using it so it's hard to tell what the best way would be.

Answer (score 0):

wkhtmltopdf is a better option. You can take screenshots of your website with it, one way is with a new store view that only your tool uses, this can then have higher resolution images in the thumbnails, svg version of the logo and the buttons hidden.

Comment: Thanks you for help, but I don't need to print screenshots  of my websites, but a simple version of products list like an excel page.

Comment: exactly. Do it with a theme/store view that has a tailored css. wysiwyg with wkhtmltopdf, you will be spending ages doing it differently.

Comment: Ok, can you explain a little more how can I do it with theme/store ?